# Reading data from Firestore in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, ios-app-group, read-data

I am currently developing an IOS app, and I need a database! I've chosen the google firestore! I need to read some fields I create that have subfields!
Something like this:

```
db.collection("usersorders").document(uid).collection("order").addDocument(data: ["items":0, "order":["Book1":0,"Book2":0,"Book3":0]]){ (error) in
                
                if error != nil {
                    // Show error message
                    print("Error saving user data")
                }
            }
```

Where I need to read the "Book1" value for example! I've looked in a lot of places, but I can't seem to find what I am looking for. Read subfields, from a field of a document!

```
@IBAction func AddtoCart(_ sender: Any) {
    let uid = user!.uid
    let docRef = db.collection("usersorders").document(user!.uid).collection("order").document()


    docRef.getDocument(source: .cache) { (document, error) in
        if let document  = document {
            let Book1  = document.get("Book1")
            let Items = document.get("items")
            
            let Book1now = Book1 as! Int + 1
            let Itemsnow = Items as! Int + 1
            
            
                  
        
}
    }}
```

This is what I have been doing but it doesn't work! After writing the code to update the database with the Items/Book1 now values it just doesn't update! Please Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your document data looks like this:

```
["items":0, "order":["Book1":0,"Book2":0,"Book3":0]]
```

You'll first need to access the `order` field in your document, before you can then find an item in that field

```
let order = document.get("order")
```

As far as I can see, this makes `order` a dictionary, so you can get the specific value from it with:

```
let book1 = order["Book1"] as Int
```

Comment: Thanks, I am really stupid! I was trying to do this with one

Comment: Oh, it **might** be possible with one `document.get("order.Book1")`. But I'm not sure if `get()` takes dotted paths, while I **know** the approach in my answer works. :)